# Why are muiltiple users not showing in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc

The code only shows yourself and no one else
Using Express, Socket.io, WebRTC, Nodejs, Jquery, And Nodemon
I am following a tutorial
on WebRTC, The goal is to make a google-meet clone
I tested the source code from my tutorial
it worked!
but my code isn't working
I don't know why tho'

Using NPM 8.1.x

Using Node 14.18.x

Using Express 4.17.x

Using Socket.io 4.4.x

Using Nodemon 2.0.x

Using JQuery 3.4.x

Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WittyChat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/Assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/Assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-1fOn6VtTq3PWwfsOrk45LnYcGosJwzMHv+Xh/Jx5303FVOXzEnw0EpLv30mtjmlj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
      </script>      
    <script src="public/Assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/Assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

        var meeting_id = urlParams.get('meetingID');
        user_id = window.prompt('Enter Your Username/UserID');

        if(!user_id || !meeting_id) {
            alert('ERROR WC0139 | Invalid/Missing Username/UserID or MeetingID');
            window.location.href="/action.html";
            return;
        }
        $("#meetingContainer").show();

        MyApp._init(user_id, meeting_id);
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main class=" d-flex flex-column home-wrap">
        <div class="g-top text-light">
            <div class="top-remote-video-show-wrap d-flex">
                <div id="meetingContainer"  style="flex-basis: 75%;">
                <div class="call-wrap" style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="video-wrap" id="divUsers" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
                    <div id="me" class="userbox display-center flex-column">
                        <h2 class="display-center" style="font-size: 14px;"></h2>
                        <div class="display-center">
                            <video autoplay muted id="locaVideoPlayer"></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="otherTemplate" class="userbox display-center flex-column" style="display:none">
                        <h2 class="display-center" style="font-size: 14px;"></h2>
                        <div class="display-center">
                            <video autoplay muted></video>
                            <audio autoplay controls style="display:none"></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="g-right-details-wrap bg-light text-secondary h-100" style="flex-basis: 25%;  z-index: 1; display: none;">
                <div class="meeting-heading-wrap d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pr-3 pl-3" style="height: 10vh;">
                    <div class="meeting-heading font-weight-bold ">Meeing Details</div>
                    <div class="meeting-heading-cross display-center cursor-pointer">
                        <span class="material-icons">clear</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="people-chat-wrap d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ml-3 mr-3 pr-3 pl-3" style="height: 10vh;font-size: 14px;">
                    <div class="people-heading display-center cursor-pointer">
                        <div class="people-headin-icon display-center mr-1">
                            <span class="material-icons">people</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="people-headin-text display-center">
                            Participant  (<span class="participant-count">1</span>)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-heading d-flex just-content-round align-items-center cursor-pointer">
                        <div class="chat-heading-icon display-center mr-1">
                            <span class="material-icons">
                                message
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-heading-text">
                            Chat
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="in-call-chat-wrap mr-3 ml-3 pl-3 pr-3" style="font-size: 14px; height: 69vh; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <div class="in-call-wrap-up" style="display: none !important;">
                        <div class="in-call-wrap d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                            <div class="participant-img-name-wrap display-center cursor-pointer">
                                <div class="participant-img">
                                    <img src="public/Assets/images/other.jpg" alt="" class="border border-secondary" style="height: 40px;width: 40px;border-radius: 50%;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="participant-name ml-2">You</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="participant-action-wrap display-center">
                                <div class="participant-action-dot display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer">
                                    <span class="material-icons">
                                        more_vert
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="participant-action-pin display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer">
                                    <span class="material-icons">
                                        push_pin
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-show-wrap text-secondary  flex-column justify-content-between h-100" style="font-size: 14px; display: flex;">
                        <div class="chat-message-show" id="messages"></div>
                        <div class="chat-message-sent d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="margin-bottom:35px">
                            <div class="chat-message-sent-input" style="width: 85%;">
                                <input type="text" name="" class="chat-message-sent-input-field w-100" id="msgbox" placeholder="Send a message to everyone" style="border-bottom: 1px solid teal; border: none;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="chat-message-sent-action display-center" id="btnsend" style="color: teal; cursor:pointer;">
                                <span class="material-icons">send</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


            </div>
            <div class="g-top-left bg-light text-secondary w-25 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-2 pr-2">
                <div class="top-left-participant-wrap pt-2 cursor-pointer">
                    <div class="top-left-participant-icon">
                        <span class="material-icons">people</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-left-participant-count participant-count">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="top-left-chat-wrap pt-2 cursor-pointer">
                    <span class="material-icons">message</span>
                </div>
                <div class="top-left-time-wrap"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="g-bottom bg-light m-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="bottom-left d-flex" style="height:10vh">
                <div class="g-details border border-success mb-2" style="display: none;min-height: 19.5vh;">
                    <div class="g-details-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom pb-1">
                        <div class="g-details-heading-detail d-flex align-items-center cursor-pointer">
                            <span class="material-icons">error</span style="margin-top:-5px">Details<span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="g-details-heading-attachment d-flex align-items-center cursor-pointer">
                            <span class="material-icons">attachment</span style="margin-top:-5px">Attachment<span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g-details-heading-show-wrap">
                            <div class="g-details-heading-show">
                                <div style="font-weight: 600;color:gray">Joining Info</div>
                                <div class="meeting_url" style="padding: 5px 0;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"></div>
                                <div style="cursor: pointer;">
                                    <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 14px;">content_copy</span>
                                    <span class="copy_info font-weight-bold">Copy Joining Info <span style="display: none;background-color: aquamarine; border-radius: 5px;" class="link-conf font-weight-bold p-1">Link Copied</span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="g-details-heading-show-attachment" style="display: none;position: relative;">
                                <div class="show-attach-file"></div>
                                <div class="upload-attach-file">
                                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" ref="uploadForm" class="display-center" id="uploadForm" style="justify-content: space-between;">
                                        <div class="custom-file" style="flex-basis:79%">
                                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="imagefile">
                                            <label for="customFile" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="share-button-wrap">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm share-attach" style="flex-basis:19%;padding: 6px 20px;">Share</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="display-center cursor-pointer meeting-details-button">
                    Meeting Details<span class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</span>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-middle d-flex just-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 10vh;">
                <div class="mic-toggle-wrap action-icon-style display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer" id="miceMuteUnmute">
                    <span class="material-icons" style="width: 100%;">mic_off</span>
                </div>
                <div class="end-call-wrap action-icon-style display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer">
                    <span class="material-icons text-danger">call</span>
                </div>
                <div class="video-toggle-wrap action-icon-style display-center cursor-pointer" id="videoCamOnOff"><span class="material-icons" style="width: 100%;">videocam_off</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-right d-flex just-content-center align-items-center mr-3" id="screenShare-wrap" style="height: 10vh;">
                <div class="present-now-wrap d-flex just-content-center flex-column align-items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer" id="ScreenShareOnOf">
                    <span class="material-icons">present_to_all</span>
                    <div>Present Now</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="option-wrap cursor-pointer display-center" style="height: 10vh; position:relative;">
                    <div class="recording-show">
                        <button class="btn btn-dark text-danger start-record">Start Recording</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option-icon">
                        <span class="material-icons">more_vert</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-box-show" style="display: none;">
            
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
const path = require("path");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
  });
  const fs = require("fs");
  const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    allowEIO3: true, // false by default
  });
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "")));


  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "")));
  var userConnections = [];
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("socket id is ", socket.id);
    socket.on("userconnect", (data) => {
      console.log("userconnent", data.displayName, data.meetingid);
      var other_users = userConnections.filter(
        (p) => p.meeting_id == data.meetingid
      );
      userConnections.push({
        connectionId: socket.id,
        user_id: data.displayName,
        meeting_id: data.meetingid,
      });
        other_users.forEach((v) => {
            socket.to(v.conncetionId).emit("imform_others_about_me", {
                other_users: data.displayName,
                connId: socket.id
            })
        });
        socket.on("SDPProcess", (data) => {
            socket.to(data.to_connid).emit("SDPProcess", {
                message: data.message,
                from_connid: socket.id,

            })
        });
    });
    socket.emit("infrom_me_about_other_user",);
}
)
```

App.js

```
    var peers_connection_ids = [];
    var peers_connection = [];
    var remote_vid_stream = [];
    var remote_aud_stream = [];
    var local_div;
    var serverProcess;
    var audio;
    var isAudioMute = true;
    var rtp_aud_senders = [];
    var video_states = {
        None: 0,
        Camera: 1,
        ScreenShare: 2
        // This code is here because in order to turn on and off the video you need to declare a var containing the states of the video e.g Off:0 On:1
    }
    var video_st = video_states.None;
    var videoCamTrack;
    var rtp_vid_senders = [];
    async function _init(SDP_function, my_connid) {
        serverProcess = SDP_function;
        my_connection_id = my_connid;
        eventProcess();
        local_div = document.getElementById("locaVideoPlayer");
    }
    function eventProcess() {
        $("#miceMuteUnmute").on("click", async function () {
            if (!audio) {
                await loadAudio();
            }
            if (!audio) {
                alert("Audio Permission has been denied!");
                return;
            }
            if (isAudioMute) {
                audio.enabled = true;
                $(this).html("<span class='material-icons>mic</span>");
                updateMediaSenders(audio, rtp_aud_senders);
            } else {
                audio.enabled = false;
                $(this).html("<span class='material-icons>mic-off</span>");
                removeMediaSenders(rtp_aud_senders);
            }
            isAudioMute = !isAudioMute;


        });
        $("#videoCamOnOff").on("click", async function () {
            if (video_st == video_states.Camera) {
                await videoProcess(video_states.None);
            } else {
                await videoProcess(video_states.Camera);
            }
        });
        $("#ScreenShareOnOf").on("click", async function () {
            if (video_st == video_states.ScreenShare) {
                await videoProcess(video_states.None);
            } else {
                await videoProcess(video_states.ScreenShare);
            }
        });
    }

    async function updateMediaSenders(track, rtp_senders) {
        for (var con_id in peers_connection_ids) {
          if (connection_status(peers_connection[con_id])) {
            if (rtp_senders[con_id] && rtp_senders[con_id].track) {
              rtp_senders[con_id].replaceTrack(track);
            } else {
              rtp_senders[con_id] = peers_connection[con_id].addTrack(track);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      function removeMediaSenders(rtp_senders) {
        for (var con_id in peers_connection_ids) {
          if (rtp_senders[con_id] && connection_status(peers_connection[con_id])) {
            peers_connection[con_id].removeTrack(rtp_senders[con_id]);
            rtp_senders[con_id] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      function removeVideoStream(rtp_vid_senders) {
        if (videoCamTrack) {
          videoCamTrack.stop();
          videoCamTrack = null;
          local_div.srcObject = null;
          removeMediaSenders(rtp_vid_senders);
        }
      }

async function videoProcess(newVideoState) {
    if (newVideoState == video_states.None) {
      $("#videoCamOnOff").html(
        "<span class='material-icons' style='width:100%;'>videocam_off</span>"
      );
      $("#ScreenShareOnOf").html(
        '<span class="material-icons">present_to_all</span><div>Present Now</div>'
      );
      video_st = newVideoState;

      removeVideoStream(rtp_vid_senders);
      return;
    }
    if (newVideoState == video_states.Camera) {
      $("#videoCamOnOff").html(
        "<span class='material-icons' style='width:100%;'>videocam_on</span>"
      );
    }
    try {
      var vstream = null;
      if (newVideoState == video_states.Camera) {
        vstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
          },
          audio: false,
        });
      } else if (newVideoState == video_states.ScreenShare) {
        vstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
          video: {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
          },
          audio: false,
        });
        vstream.oninactive = (e) => {
          removeVideoStream(rtp_vid_senders);
          $("#ScreenShareOnOf").html(
            '<span class="material-icons ">present_to_all</span><div >Present Now</div>'
          );
        };
      }
      if (vstream && vstream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
        videoCamTrack = vstream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        if (videoCamTrack) {
          local_div.srcObject = new MediaStream([videoCamTrack]);
          alert("Video Cam found")
          updateMediaSenders(videoCamTrack, rtp_vid_senders);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }
    video_st = newVideoState;
    if (newVideoState == video_states.Camera) {
      $("#videoCamOnOff").html(
        '<span class="material-icons" style="width: 100%;">videocam</span>'
      );
      $("#ScreenShareOnOf").html(
        '<span class="material-icons ">present_to_all</span><div >Present Now</div>'
      );
    } else if (newVideoState == video_states.ScreenShare) {
      $("#videoCamOnOff").html(
        '<span class="material-icons" style="width: 100%;">videocam_off</span>'
      );
      $("#ScreenShareOnOf").html(
        '<span class="material-icons text-success">present_to_all</span><div class="text-success">Stop Present Now</div>'
      );
    }
  }
  var iceConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
      },
      {
        urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
      },
    ],
  };

  async function setConnection(connid) {
    var connection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

    connection.onnegotiationneeded = async function (event) {
      await setOffer(connid);
    };
    connection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
      if (event.candidate) {
        serverProcess(
          JSON.stringify({ icecandidate: event.candidate }),
          connid
        );
      }
    };
    connection.ontrack = function (event) {
      if (!remote_vid_stream[connid]) {
        remote_vid_stream[connid] = new MediaStream();
      }
      if (!remote_aud_stream[connid]) {
        remote_aud_stream[connid] = new MediaStream();
      }

      if (event.track.kind == "video") {
        remote_vid_stream[connid]
          .getVideoTracks()
          .forEach((t) => remote_vid_stream[connid].removeTrack(t));
        remote_vid_stream[connid].addTrack(event.track);
        var remoteVideoPlayer = document.getElementById("v_" + connid);
        remoteVideoPlayer.srcObject = null;
        remoteVideoPlayer.srcObject = remote_vid_stream[connid];
        remoteVideoPlayer.load();
      } else if (event.track.kind == "audio") {
        remote_aud_stream[connid]
          .getAudioTracks()
          .forEach((t) => remote_aud_stream[connid].removeTrack(t));
        remote_aud_stream[connid].addTrack(event.track);
        var remoteAudioPlayer = document.getElementById("a_" + connid);
        remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = null;
        remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = remote_aud_stream[connid];
        remoteAudioPlayer.load();
      }
    };
    peers_connection_ids[connid] = connid;
    peers_connection[connid] = connection;

    if (
      video_st == video_states.Camera ||
      video_st == video_states.ScreenShare
    ) {
      if (videoCamTrack) {
        updateMediaSenders(videoCamTrack, rtp_vid_senders);
      }
    }

    return connection;
  }

    async function setOffer(connid) {
        var connection = peers_connection[connid];
        var offer = await connection.createOffer();
        await connection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        serverProcess(JSON.stringify({
            offer: connection.localDescription,
        }), connid);
    }
    async function SDPProcess(message, from_connid) {
        message = JSON.parse(message);
        if (message.answer) {
          await peers_connection[from_connid].setRemoteDescription(
            new RTCSessionDescription(message.answer)
          );
        } else if (message.offer) {
          if (!peers_connection[from_connid]) {
            await setConnection(from_connid);
          }
          await peers_connection[from_connid].setRemoteDescription(
            new RTCSessionDescription(message.offer)
          );
          var answer = await peers_connection[from_connid].createAnswer();
          await peers_connection[from_connid].setLocalDescription(answer);
          serverProcess(
            JSON.stringify({
              answer: answer,
            }),
            from_connid
          );
        } else if (message.icecandidate) {
          if (!peers_connection[from_connid]) {
            await setConnection(from_connid);
          }
          try {
            await peers_connection[from_connid].addIceCandidate(
              message.icecandidate
            );
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
      }
      return {
        setNewConnection: async function (connid) {
          await setConnection(connid);
        },
        init: async function (SDP_function, my_connid) {
          await _init(SDP_function, my_connid);
        },
        processClientFunc: async function (data, from_connid) {
          await SDPProcess(data, from_connid);
        },
        closeConnectionCall: async function (connid) {
          await closeConnection(connid);
        },
      };
    })();
    var MyApp = (function () {
        var socket = null;
        var user_id = "";
        var meeting_id = "";
        function init(uid, mid) {
          user_id = uid;
          meeting_id = mid;
          $("#meetingContainer").show();
          $("#me h2").text(user_id + "(Me)");
          document.title = user_id;
          event_process_for_signalling_server();
        }
    function event_process_for_signalling_server() {
        socket = io();

        var SDP_function = function (data, to_connid) {
            socket.emit("SDPProcess", {
              message: data,
              to_connid: to_connid,
            });
          };

          socket.on("connect", () => {
            if (socket.connected) {
              AppProcess.init(SDP_function, socket.id);
              if (user_id != "" && meeting_id != "") {
                socket.emit("userconnect", {
                  displayName: user_id,
                  meetingid: meeting_id,
                });
              }
            }
          });
          socket.on("inform_others_about_me", function (data) {
            addUser(data.other_user_id, data.connId, data.userNumber);
      
            AppProcess.setNewConnection(data.connId);
          });
          socket.on("inform_me_about_other_user", function (other_users) {
            var userNumber = other_users.length;
            var userNumb = userNumber + 1;
            if (other_users) {
              for (var i = 0; i < other_users.length; i++) {
                addUser(
                  other_users[i].user_id,
                  other_users[i].connectionId,
                  userNumb
                );
                AppProcess.setNewConnection(other_users[i].connectionId);
              }
            }
          });
        socket.on("SDPProcess", async function (data) {
            await AppProcess.processClientFunc(data.message, data.from_connid);
        })
    }
    function addUser(other_user_id, connId, userNum) {
        var newDivId = $("#otherTemplate").clone();
        newDivId = newDivId.attr("id", connId).addClass("other");
        newDivId.find("h2").text(other_user_id);
        newDivId.find("video").attr("id", "v_" + connId);
        newDivId.find("audio").attr("id", "a_" + connId);
        newDivId.show();
        $("#divUsers").append(newDivId);
        $(".in-call-wrap-up").append(
          '<div class="in-call-wrap d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3" id="participant_' +
            connId +
            '"> <div class="participant-img-name-wrap display-center cursor-pointer"> <div class="participant-img"> <img src="public/Assets/images/other.jpg" alt="" class="border border-secondary" style="height: 40px;width: 40px;border-radius: 50%;"> </div> <div class="participant-name ml-2"> ' +
            other_user_id +
            '</div> </div> <div class="participant-action-wrap display-center"> <div class="participant-action-dot display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer"> <span class="material-icons"> more_vert </span> </div> <div class="participant-action-pin display-center mr-2 cursor-pointer"> <span class="material-icons"> push_pin </span> </div> </div> </div>'
        );
        $(".participant-count").text(userNum);
      }
    return {
        _init: function (uid, mid) {
            init(uid, mid);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: Ok, i will do it